# Check whether positive integral solution $(x,y)$ exists for $ax + by = n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, linear-diophantine-equations

Is there any method to check whether there exist positive integral solutions $(x,y)$ for the equation

$$ax + by = n $$ 
given
$$a,b,n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$$

Also, please note $a$ and $b$ were given, and the following relations exist:

1. $a > b$
2. $a + b \le n$

Comment: also please note $a$ and $b$ where given and there exist following relation $a > b$ and $ a + b <= n $

Comment: If there are more conditions, you should add them in your post, not in the comments. Simply click on [edit] and add the conditions which are missing.

Comment: added to post, thank you

Comment: If $\gcd(a,b) \mid n$, then there is a solution.

Comment: I think the condition $gcd(a,b) | n $ is for integral solutions while I am interested in only positive integral solutions. Please correct me if i am missing any thing

Answer (score 4):

Note that $\mathbb Z^+ = \{1,2,3,\dots\}.$

[The Chicken McNugget Theorem](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Chicken_McNugget_Theorem) (or Postage Stamp Problem or Frobenius Coin Problem) states that for any two relatively prime positive integers $a,b$, the greatest integer that cannot be written in the form $ax+by$ for nonnegative integers $x,y$ is $(a-1)(b-1)-1 = ab-a-b.$

A corollary of the proof states that every integer $c \ge (a-1)(b-1)$ can be written in the form $ax+by=c$, where $x,y \in \mathbb Z^+$, in exactly one way. So you may want to also exclude multiples of $a$ and multiples of $b$ since they require that either $x$ or $y$ be equal to $0$.

Comment: $\mathbb Z^+ = \{1,2,3,\dots\}$ according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Notation) and [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Z-Plus.html).

Comment: @Maurice - and that's the way I use it. But I have seen it used differently.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an outline of an answer based on Section 5.1, "The Equation $ax + by = c$," of I. Niven, H. S. Zuckerman, H. L. Montgomery, *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers,* 5th ed., Wiley (New York), 1991.  You can prove the statements with the help of [this theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#One_equation).

There is a positive solution if and only if

- $n$ is a multiple of gcd($a ,b$) = $g$, and
- $n > ab/g$.

To understand that second requirement, let $(x_0, y_0)$ be one solution.  Then the solutions are of the form
$$\left(x_0 + \frac{kb}{g}, y_0 - \frac{ka}{g}\right)$$
where $k$ is an integer, so you want to find $k$ such that
$$x_0 + \frac{kb}{g} > 0, \text{ and } y_0 - \frac{ka}{g} > 0,$$
which is equivalent to
$$\frac{-gx_0}{b} < k < \frac{gy_0}{a}.$$
Because $(x_0, y_0)$ satisfies $ax + by = n$, the length of that open interval for $k$ is $gn/(ab)$.  A gap for you to fill in is to prove why that length must be greater than $1$ for there to be a positive solution.